# iOS 12.2 beta: Keyboard not showing

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I tested my Ionic App on iOS 12.2 beta and found out that keyboard is not being opened when focusing on text element. It seems like that element isn't getting focused at all. This works perfectly on previous iOS versions.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple changed the method name used for the autofocus.
It’s been fixed on the plugin to use the new name when available, will be released today
https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/pull/334